# 08 Audi A4 B7 2.0T DTC P0503 speed sensor erractic/high

Tags: audi, dtc, a4

I just finished reinstalling the intake manifold after cleaning the valves and went to start the car. It starts for about 2 seconds before shutting itself down. It throws 6 pending codes. P0503 - Speed (RPM) sensor erratic/high,
C0203,
C1103,
C1403,
C1203,
C1300.
I don't think I did anything to mess with the speed sensor. Any ideas?

Edit:

startup video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cjn7k4ny480y70/A4%20Startup.mov?dl=0

Engine Stats right before shutdown: 
[image: Engine Stats]

OBD DTC: 
[image: OBD Trouble Codes]

UPDATE #2:
         So it turns out that my OBD reader was giving me the wrong codes. The real codes were P0351-354, all referring to the ignition coils (which I replaced at the same time). The car starts, registers the fault and then shuts down the injectors. They are the correct coils, and obviously they are getting current because the car starts.. why would it register those codes. I've reseated them checked all the connections. Unfortunately I didnt keep the old coils.

Comment: When you clear the codes, do all 6 come right back upon attempted restart?

Comment: they do, I've repeated it about 8 times now

Comment: Did you recheck the connection at the sensor to ensure complete and secure connection?

Comment: to be honest I'm not even sure where that sensor is. I've been googling for a while trying to find a diagram.

Comment: The P0503 says it's for the *vehicle* speed sensor, yet what you are giving me and the notes about it suggest it's an *engine* speed sensor (such as 4 tics per engine revolution). Doesn't make sense to me. I'll continue looking though.

Comment: It is the RPM sensor. Here is a photo of what I think might be it https://www.dropbox.com/s/z86q255426sv09q/A4%20trans.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Looks like you are out of gas :)

Comment: Do you have access to fuel trim information?

Comment: what would be the best way to get that info? Currently I'm using a bluetooth OBD adapter to connect it to my iphone.

Comment: If you don't have access to any parameters like STFT/LTFT (short-term, long-term fuel trims), O2 sensor voltage readouts over a period of time will do. I'll need to confirm this, but your vehicle probably has two banks, with two sensors on each bank - total 4 sensor voltages. I understand the vehicle isn't staying on though, so this may be a tall order anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can *try* replacing the Engine Crank Angle Sensor, which I believe is the one which is playing erratic. The sensor looks like this:

[image]

So it is the one you are looking at in the picture. Who knows why it's gone bad, but with the code you mentioned, this seems like the culprit.

[This is a very good video on the replacement of the sensor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LldC6CuXYoQ) The only thing I'd say about what he does to replace it is, don't mess with the throttle while trying to crank your engine. On many (not sure about the VAG engines), your throttle position sensor will get screwy readings when you do that and your car won't run right again until you do a reset.

Overall, this is a *very* easy thing to do. You may even be able to do the exchange from the top side (instead of removing the cover).

Comment: Yeah, I found that sensor down on my crankcase, but the problem is that I wasn't working anywhere near that and the car was running fine prior to me taking the intake off. The odds of that going bad at the exact same time just seems like an unlikely coincidence. But thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: You could be right, but in this case you might want to apply [Ockham's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). In this case, this is the simple theory which would explain. That's where the engine code points to. You could first look to ensure you have proper connectivity along the wiring involved with the sensor. Seeing as how it is not a completely fault, I doubt wiring issues would have anything to do with it. I have seen stranger issues appear by the same manner as what you are suggesting.

Comment: I agree and I did check the wires and connection up to the bundle and they all seemed fine.

Comment: Since the problem is *intermittent/erratic/high* and not a complete failure, the only way you'd be able to tell is through replacement. I absolutely hate *remove & replace* mechanicing, but in this case, it may be your only choice.

Comment: I also get a lot of C-codes. Do you think there is any chance that these codes are thrown in the event of an unsuccessful start. Also my friend broke the clip on the camshaft position sensor, but the pins all seemed fine. Maybe that is the cause of the code..?

Comment: I couldn't even find any information on your *C* codes, so cannot speak to them. I'm assuming they are specific to your vehicle. As far as the clip, if you are talking about the retaining clip which holds a connector together, it will usually not cause an issue. It's the connection which you really need. The clip just ensures it doesn't slip. As long as the connector itself is in place, you can use a zip tie to keep it together. You could try and cinch one down and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: There is an issue with this answer. Looking up the P0503 code, it is specific to the *vehicle* speed sensor, not the engine speed sensor. The crankshaft position sensor has specific codes (P0335-P0339 & P0385-P0389) and the camshaft has specific codes (P0340-P0344). The P0503 should *not* cause any running issues with the vehicle. It would just throw the code and may cause issues with ABS, but should have nothing to do with the engine.

Comment: The *C* codes have to do with the chassis, so would fall into the realm of the speed sensor. Again, these would have nothing to do with why your engine will not run for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: from my understanding, there's very few things that will cause a vehicle to shut itself down (presumably what mine is doing) a bad camshaft or crankshaft sensor or a catastrophic fuel or air leak. It's just interesting that I'm not getting a definitive code that would point to a conclusion

Answer (score 0):

All your codes are from different areas but can be from the same place. It's ABS, Brakes, Axle solenoids and so on.

I suppose you or your mechanics forgot to connect one of big connectors with several wires that are causing your problems. Try to look for unplugged connectors under your trunk

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is the ABS/ESP control unit located in the vicinity of the intake manifold? Did you try removing the connector of ABS/ESP control unit?Check whether the ABS/ESP control unit is communicating with the scanner. All the fault codes point to issue in ABS/ESP control unit